# Filling in the months and years in date range?

Tags: sas, time-series

I am new to SAS and wondered how to most efficiently list the months and years that fall between a starting date and ending date, in addition to the starting and ending date themselves.  I've read about the INTCK and INTNX functions, the EXPAND function for time series data, and even CALENDAR FILL, but I'm not sure how to use them for this particular purpose.  This task is easy to accomplish manually with a small dataset in Excel thanks to the drag-down autofill feature, but I need to find a way to do this in SAS due to the size of the dataset.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

The dataset is in a large text file organized like this now:

```
ID          Start               End
1000        08/01/2012          12/31/2012
1001        07/01/2010          05/31/2011
1002        04/01/1990          10/31/1991
```

But the output should look like this in the end:

```
ID      MonthYear
1000    08/12
1000    09/12
1000    10/12
1000    11/12
1000    12/12
1001    07/10
1001    08/10
1001    09/10
1001    10/10
1001    11/10
1001    12/10
1001    01/11
1001    02/11
1001    03/11
1001    04/11
1001    05/11
1002    04/90
1002    05/90
1002    06/90
1002    07/90
1002    08/90
1002    09/90
1002    10/90
1002    11/90
1002    12/90
1002    01/91
1002    02/91
1002    03/91
1002    04/91
1002    05/91
1002    06/91
1002    07/91
1002    08/91
1002    09/91
1002    10/91
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
data want2;
  set have;
  do i = 0 to intck('month',start,end);
      monthyear=intnx('month',start,i,'b');
      output;
      end;
   format monthyear monyy.;
   keep id monthyear;
   run;
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick.  PROC EXPAND may be more efficient, though I think it requires a number of desired observations rather than a start/end combination (though you could get that, I suppose).

```
data have;
informat start end MMDDYY10.;
input ID          Start               End;
datalines;
1000        08/01/2012          12/31/2012
1001        07/01/2010          05/31/2011
1002        04/01/1990          10/31/1991
;;;;
run;

data want;
set have;
format monthyear MMYYS5.;    *formats the numeric monthyear variable with your desired format;
monthyear=start;             *start with the initial observation;
output;                      *output it;
do _t = 1 by 1 until (month(monthyear)=month(end)); *iterate until end;
  monthyear = intnx('month',monthyear,1,'b');       *go to the next start of month;
  output;                                           *output it;
end;
run;
```